# How do I parse a text file into different elements of a struct in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, text, struct

I know that parsing questions similar to this are asked a lot here, but after having searched for a while, I couldn't find an answer that helped me so hopefully I'm not asking something that has been answered a million times before.

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
1 14 100
3 34 200
2 78 120
```

The first number is an ID number, the second is an Age and the third number is a Weight. (These are arbitrary descriptions) I also have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct myData{
    int ID;
    int age;
    int weight;
};
```

After creating an array of myData structs, how do I iterate through the text so that eventually I end up with each element of each line of the text file in one index of the array? For example, after populating the array with the elements of the text file, I should be able to say

```
cout << myData[0].ID << ", " << myData[0].age << ", " << myData[0].weight << "\n";
```

and it should print out "1, 14, 100" and it should print out "3, 78, 120" if the index was 2 in the line of code above. I've tried looking for example of others using getLine() or get() and things like that but I can't seem to get the hang of it. I hope I included enough information about my question so it can be easily answered by the wizards on this site. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to me that this is homework so I'm even more tempted to say: "What have you tried yet and where are you stuck ?"

Comment: Read about the concept [serialization / deserialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). After it, paste the code you're using ;)

Comment: Look up [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream), the [input operator `>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). And of course the `while` and `for` loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
struct myData
{
    int ID;
    int age;
    int weight;

    // Add constructor, so we can create instances with the data
    myData(int i, int a, int w)
        : ID(i), age(a), weight(w)
        {}
};

std::vector<myData> input;
std::ifstream file("input.txt");

// Read input from file
int id, age, weight;
while (file >> id >> age >> weight)
{
    // Add a new instance in our vector
    input.emplace_back(id, age, weight);

    // Skip over the newline, so next input happens on next line
    std::ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

// Close the file after use
file.close();

// Print all loaded data
for (auto data : input)
{
    cout << "ID: " << data.ID << ", age: " << data.age << ", weight: " << data.weight << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What I ended up doing wasn't at all close to what you have here, but your code snippet definitely helped me get to the answer I needed to get to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the include file :
`#include <fstream>`
and simply do something similar

```
    std::ifstream infile("file.txt");
    int a, b, c;
    while (infile >> a >> b >> c)
    {
        // process (a,b,c)
    }
```

don't forget to close the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file and go through it to read all lines:

```
//Opening File
FILE *trace;
trace=fopen("//path//to//yourfile","r");

// Read the file
myData list[N];
int count=0;
while(!feof(trace)){
    fscanf(trace,"%d %d %d\n", &myData[count].ID, &myData[count].age, &myData[count].weight);
    count++;
}

// now you have an array of size N go through it and print all
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    printf("%d %d %d\n", myData[i].ID, myData[i].age, myData[i].weight);
```

Comment: This question is tagged C++, so why are you answering using C code?

Comment: As far as I know, it is perfectly valid code for C++ as well.